# How to force a figure to fill the upper part of an A4 paper, when printing on Mathematica?

Tags: printing

I have produced a figure and am trying to print it in A4 paper. How can I force the figure to fill the upper part of my page? For example, see:

> [image]

I'd like to force that figure to occupy all the upper part of the document. Also, it would be helpful to make the `Out[12]` disappear.

Comment: You can select `Out[]` and delete before printing.

Comment: Can you not click and manually resize the image before printing?

Comment: @Teabelly Yeah but that's an ugly solution. It would be better to have something that spreads the image on top.

Comment: Set the `ImageSize`/`ImageResolution` appropriately for A4 (i.e use `Show` to make it fit). You can also modify the `CellMargins` to eliminate borders